# How can I make focus event happened on the dynamically inserted input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, focus

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    console.log('input focused');
});
```

Above is my code to test if focus event happened.And I made a button to insert another input dynamically.But while I focus the inserted inputs,no console logged at all.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: I expected a <button> tag after reading that you ` made a button to insert another input dynamically'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) with the [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin) event as [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) does not support bubbling(event delegation requires bubbling support to work).

```js
$("input").focus(function() {
  snippet.log('input focus: ' + $('input').index(this));
});

$('#dynamicarea').on('focusin', 'input', function() {
  snippet.log('input focusin: ' + $('input').index(this));
});

$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').append('<input />');
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input />
<input />
<br />
<button>Add</button>
<div id="dynamicarea"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the link. I have deleted the misleading answer.Thanks for not down voted the answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function focused(evt){
    var target = evt.target;
    var target_name = evt.target.nodeName;
    $(target).keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which==9 && $(e.target).parent().parent().is(":last-of-type")){
            e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            $(this).unbind("keydown");
        }
    });
}
<sectionA>
<input>
/*insert input here*/
</sectionA>
<sectionB>
<input>
<input>
</sectionB>
```

Originally I was trying to stop focusing to the next input in the sectionB which is not in the viewport when pressing the tab. So I write a function above to bind in the inserted input to tell. But Arun's answer also work. Thanks a lot.